# Using the URLconf defined in fifteen.urls, Django tried these URL patterns

Tags: python, django, selenium, matplotlib

Page not found (404) 
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

I got error. Using the URLconf defined in vidly.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
I am getting this error while running manage.py file using command python3 manage.py runserver.

**Error**

```
Using the URLconf defined in fifteen.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^home/$
    ^home/search$
    admin/

The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class Covid19Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'covid_19'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
```

**tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase

# Create your tests here.
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from covid_19 import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$',views.greetings),
    url(r'^home/search$',views.search),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import time

# Create your views here.
def greetings(request):
    res = render(request,'covid_19/home.html')
    return res

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        state_name = request.POST['search_text'].capitalize()
        state_code_data = pd.read_csv("state_code.csv")
        print(state_code_data.head())
        state_code = state_code_data.loc[state_code_data['State'] == state_name, 'State_code'].iloc[0]
        url = "https://www.covid19india.org/state/"+state_code
        print("state name :",state_name)
        print("state code :",state_code)
        print("url :",url)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(6)
        map_div = driver.find_element(By.ID,"chart")
        html_code = map_div.get_attribute('outerHTML')

        driver.quit()
        # right hand side portion
        state_wise_daily = pd.read_csv("state_wise_daily.csv")
        print(state_wise_daily.head())
        for_confirmed = state_wise_daily.loc[state_wise_daily['Status']=="Confirmed",['Date',state_code]]
        for_confirmed.rename(columns = {state_code: "Confirmed"},inplace=True)

        for_recovered = state_wise_daily.loc[state_wise_daily['Status']=="Recovered",['Date',state_code]]
        for_recovered.rename(columns = {state_code: "Recovered"},inplace=True)

        for_deceased = state_wise_daily.loc[state_wise_daily['Status']=="Deceased",['Date',state_code]]
        for_deceased.rename(columns = {state_code: "Deceased"},inplace=True)

        temp = pd.merge(for_confirmed,for_recovered,on="Date",how="inner")
        final_state_wise = pd.merge(temp,for_deceased,on="Date",how="inner")

        final_state_wise['Active'] = final_state_wise['Confirmed'] - final_state_wise['Recovered'] - final_state_wise['Deceased']

        final_state_wise['cf_Confirmed'] = final_state_wise['Confirmed'].cumsum()
        final_state_wise['cf_Recovered'] = final_state_wise['Recovered'].cumsum()
        final_state_wise['cf_Deceased'] = final_state_wise['Deceased'].cumsum()
        final_state_wise['cf_Active'] = final_state_wise['Active'].cumsum()

        final_state_wise = final_state_wise[['Date','cf_Confirmed','cf_Recovered','cf_Deceased','cf_Active']]

        print(final_state_wise.tail(2))

        total_state_data = final_state_wise.tail(1)

        final_state_wise.Date = pd.to_datetime(final_state_wise.Date)
        final_state_wise.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

        plot = final_state_wise.plot(figsize=(20,10), linewidth=5, fontsize=20,color = ['steelBlue','Green','Red','Orange'])
        plot.set_xlabel('Date', fontsize=20)
        plot.set_ylabel('No. of Cases', fontsize=20)
        plot.set_title(state_name, fontsize=20)
        plot.legend(["Confirmed","Recovered","Death","Active"],fontsize=20)
        fig = plot.get_figure()
        fig.savefig("static/images/output.png")

        res = render(request,'covid_19/home.html',{"html_code":html_code,"state_name":state_name,"total_state_data":total_state_data,"img_name":"output.png"})
        return res
```

According to me the error is in `url.py` or `views.py`. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have re read your query and you don't have a empty URL. I believe the below should correct it.

Also I believe you are missing the / after the search

Url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from covid_19 import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/$' , views.greetings),
    url(r'^home/search/$',views.search), ]
```

Comment: if this has helped you please can you mark the answer as correct